# Tanaim in the Sanhedrin

Tags: sanhedrin

Do we know by name any *Tanainm* that actually sat at great *Sanhedrin*? (71 sages)

I know Shimon "H'tzadik" that were in the *Keneset Hagdola*, but it's not the same.

Comment: 1. Presumably, all the Zugot were a Nassi and Av B"D of "A" Sanhedrin. 2. Interestingly, a functioning Sanhedrin is never mentioned either before or after the destruction of the Temple - all the decisions in the Talmud are made elsewhere.

Comment: Interesting: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95750/why-aharon-itamar-and-elazar-were-not-part-of-the-70-elders?r=SearchResults&s=20|12.0597

Comment: On the second thought, I'm unsure of #2 so I posted a question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108348/examples-of-a-functioning-sanhedrin-in-the-talmud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [2nd Mishna in the 2nd Perek of Chagiga](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chagigah.16a.18?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) gives a list of the last 5 sets of Av Bet Din and Nasi of the Sanhedrin before the second Churban - for a total of **11 Tanaim; members of the Sanhedrin whose names we know**.

> > יוֹסֵי בֶּן יוֹעֶזֶר אוֹמֵר שֶׁלֹּא לִסְמוֹךְ, יוֹסֵי בֶּן יוֹחָנָן אוֹמֵר לִסְמוֹךְ. יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן פְּרַחְיָה אוֹמֵר שֶׁלֹּא לִסְמוֹךְ, נִתַּאי הָאַרְבֵּלִי אוֹמֵר לִסְמוֹךְ. יְהוּדָה בֶּן טַבַּאי אוֹמֵר שֶׁלֹּא לִסְמוֹךְ, שִׁמְעוֹן בֶּן שָׁטָח אוֹמֵר לִסְמוֹךְ. שְׁמַעְיָה אוֹמֵר לִסְמוֹךְ. אַבְטַלְיוֹן אוֹמֵר שֶׁלֹּא לִסְמוֹךְ. הִלֵּל וּמְנַחֵם לֹא נֶחְלְקוּ. יָצָא מְנַחֵם, נִכְנַס שַׁמַּאי. שַׁמַּאי אוֹמֵר שֶׁלֹּא לִסְמוֹךְ, הִלֵּל אוֹמֵר לִסְמוֹךְ. **הָרִאשׁוֹנִים הָיוּ נְשִׂיאִים, וּשְׁנִיִּים לָהֶם אַב בֵּית דִּין**:‏
>
> **Yose ben Yoezer** says that [on a festival] the laying of the hands [on the head of a sacrifice] should not be performed. 
> **Yose ben Johanan** says that it should be performed.
>  **Joshua ben Perachia** says that it should not be performed. 
> **Nittai the Arbelite** says that it should be performed. 
> **Judah ben Tabai** says that it should not be performed. 
> **Shimon ben Shetach** says that it should  be performed. 
> **Shamayah** says that it should be performed. 
> **Avtalyon** says that it should not be performed. 
> Hillel and Menahem did not dispute. **Menahem** left, Shammai entered. 
> **Shammai** says that it should not be performed. 
> **Hillel** says that it should be performed.
>  **The first members of each pair served as Nasi, and their counterparts served as Av Beis Din (deputy Nasi) of the courts.**.

Comment: Some more sages held the titles, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Following @Danny's answer, More sages that held the titles, therefore been in the great *sanhedrin*:

*Nasi*:
It could be that Shimon Ben Shetach was a *Nasi*, and not *Av Beis Din*.
Shimon Ben Hilel
Raban Gamliel *hazaken* (the elder)
Raban Shimon Ben Gamliel *hazaken* (the elder)
Raban Yochanan Ben Zakai
Raban Gamliel of Yavne*, part time in rotation with Rabbi Elazar Ben Azaria
*Also *Av Beis Din*

*Av Beis Din*:
Rabbi Yehoshua Ben Hanania

After this era, there are more sages carrying the title, but it could be that the authority of the *sanhedrin* was impaired, so It wasn't a fully operating *sanhedrin*:

*Nasi*:
Raban Shimon Ben Gamliel II
Rabbi Yehuda H-Nasi
Raban Gamliel III
Rabbi Yehuda Nessia
Raban Gamliel IV
Rabbi Yehuda Nessia II
Hilel Nessia
Raban Gamliel V
Rabbi Yehuda Nessia III
Raban Gamliel VI

*Av Beis Din*:
Rabbi Natan
Rabbi Efes
Rabbi Hanina bar Hama

So, 7 more names for sure, maybe even 20.